Node.JS And PostgresDB : I can not use pool
I want to make some function (as SelectDB) that send SQL statement then return the queried data.
But when call SelectDB a second time, I get this error:

Error: Client has already been connected. You cannot reuse a client.

However in SelectDB has call to closing (client.end) already

result of first calling is already shown
However logtime to Settimeout it has still error.
"This the DB Provider not allow to use connection Pool"

const { promises } = require('dns');
const fs = require('fs');
const pg = require('pg');
const url = require('url');
module.exports.pg=pg
const config = {
    statement_timeout: 100,
    user: "avnadmin",
    password: "AVN*******2f",
    host: "p*****ncloud.com",
    port: 26239,
    database: "****et",
    ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: true,
        ca: `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIE*****QYJKoZIhvc****************************************NAQEM
BQAwOjE4MDYGA1UEAwwvY2E5ZWFmZGQtOTcwMC00MTYxLTg4MTktODA2N2MwNGVj
-----END CERTIFICATE-----`,
    },
};
const clien=new pg.Client(config);
function connecting(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        clien.connect(function(ConErr){
            if(ConErr){
                reject("Inside connecting Error When connect : "+ConErr)
            }else{
                //console.log("Inside connecting success when connect")
                resolve("Inside connecting success when connect")
            }
        })
    })
}

function querying(SqlState,data) {
    return QueryPromis = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        clien.query(SqlState,data,(QuryErr,result) => {
            if(QuryErr) {
                reject("Inside querying error when query : "+QuryErr)
            } else {
                console.log("Inside querying success when query")
                resolve(result.rows)
            }
        })
    })
}

function closing() {
    return ClosePromisr = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        clien.end((CloseErr)=>{
            if(CloseErr){
                reject("Inside closing error when query : "+CloseErr)
            }else{
                //console.log("Inside closing success when query")
                resolve("Inside closing success when query")
            }
        })
    })
}

async function SelectDB(sql,params) {
    try{
        console.log("in SelectDB"+await connecting())
        const data = await querying(sql,params)
        console.log(data)
        console.log("in SelectDB"+await closing())
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
}
/////////////////////////------------------- Call function ------------
SelectDB(`SELECT * FROM public."Brand";`,)
setTimeout(() => {
    SelectDB(`SELECT * FROM public."DocNumber";`,)
}, 3000);`

Expect can call second and third ..... when end application.
